# Replace special character and null values with mode in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to replace the special character '?' and null values with the most frequent values in pandas dataframe. I did them separately but I was wondering if there a way to do them in one code.
This is what I did

Thank you in advance

```
df['FirstName'] = df['FirstName'].str.replace('[?]', '') 

replace = df['FirstName'].fillna(df["FirstName"].mode()[0], inplace=True)
```

a sub of the data frame

```
    FirstName   LastName    Year     Department
83  Joe                     ?        Public Library
84               Benton     5        ?
85  Sarah        Cronin              Public Library
86  Gabriel        ?        2        Resource Recovery
87  ?           Andrade     3
```

Comment: Please post an example of your dataframe. And is the code you 've tried, working?

Comment: This question probably is for Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LoukasPap I have added a sub of my data frame. The first code I could not know how to replace the '?' with the mode, it just replace it with null. The second code is replacing the null values with the mode but not the null values that replaced by the first code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me

```
df = df.replace('?', np.NaN)
replace = df.fillna(df.mode().iloc[0], inplace=True)
```

I first replace '?' with null, then replace the null with mode.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you try immediately replacing with the most frequent values:

```py
df['FirstName'] = df['FirstName'].str.replace('[?]', df["FirstName"].mode()[0])
```